# Refreshing fragment in Async task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

My result should be like  showing images and text in each fragment. 
i am using fragments in the view pager

As images are high resolution, i am downloading it using async task and saving in sdcard .

If the images are downloaded , my code is working properly , If the images are not there , after downloading images , fragments are not getting refreshed and thus images are not getting displayed . How to refresh a fragment after completing image download.

My code in activity to set fragment is

```
   ExtendedViewPager pager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    /** Getting fragment manager */
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    /** Instantiating FragmentPagerAdapter */
    pagerAdapter = new MyGalleryPagerAdapter(fm,eventArrayList);

    /** Setting the pagerAdapter to the pager object */
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyPageChangeListener());
    pager.setCurrentItem(currentpage);
```

My adapter code is

```
public class MyGalleryPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements{
 public static int mCurrentPage;
/** Constructor of the class 
 * @param eventArrayList */
ArrayList<EventsGalleryDetails> events;
public MyGalleryPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<EventsGalleryDetails>    eventArrayList) {
    super(fm);
    events=eventArrayList;
}

/** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    System.out.println("Get Item");
    MyGallery myFragment = new MyGallery();
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("current_page", arg0);
    myFragment.setArguments(data);
    mCurrentPage = arg0;
    return myFragment;
}

public int currentItem(){
    return mCurrentPage;
}

public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
        return POSITION_NONE;

}
/** Returns the number of pages */
@Override
public int getCount() {     
    return events.size();
}
```

And my fragment code is

```
 public class MyGallery extends Fragment implements OnPageChangeListener{
ImageLoader imageLoader;
int mCurrentPage;
Bitmap bm ;
public static final String TAG = "MyGallery";
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
private HashMap<Integer, TouchImageView>hmap = new HashMap<Integer, TouchImageView>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(getActivity());
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallerysecondscreenitem, container,false);               
    TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.galleryimage);
    TextView txt = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.gallerytext);
    hmap.put(mCurrentPage, img);
    if(new File(Constants.Path+".jpg").exists()){
        loadBitmap(img);
        bm = null;
        img = null;
    }else{
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallery_icon);
    }
    txt.setText(GallerySecondScreen.eventArrayList.get(mCurrentPage).getTitle());
    return v;       
}
public void loadBitmap(TouchImageView mImageView) {
     final String imageKey = String.valueOf(mCurrentPage);

        final Bitmap bitmap = mMemoryCache.get(imageKey);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallery_icon);
            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask();
            task.execute(mImageView);
        }
}
```

My asyc task for downlaoding image is

```
         private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>{
          @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... values) {
        try {
            for(int j=0;j<eventArrayList.size();j++){
                if(!new File(Constants.Path+".jpg").exists()){
                         downloadImageFromServer(eventArrayList.get(j).getImage(), ""+pos,""+j);
                    publishProgress(j);
                    //Log.d("Image will be downloaded from server now..", "the "+values[0]);
                }else{
                    publishProgress(j);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Log.d("value of j:",""+j);
        return j;
    }}
```

Please suggest a way to refresh a view after completing my Image Download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Resolved the issue by using the same pageradpter.notifydatasetchanged(). Instead of calling it every time , i called only when the image of current view got downloaded

Here is my modified OnprogressUpdate

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        System.out.println("Downloaded "+values[0]);
        if(values[0] == mPager.mCurrentPage){
            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the solution posted in my previous posts please validate it

Comment: This is not fair. You posted answer by copying @Chetu reply and marked as answered.  You shoud have accepted Chetu's reply.

Answer (score 0):

try `this.getView().draw()` if they dont work for you try `requestLayout()` or `forceLayout()`

Comment: this .getView().draw() function is not there to override and request layout () or force layout () are not working

Comment: you don't need to override it just to call it. If that doesn't work for you, the only option is to remove and re-add the fragment to you fragment transaction. The commit call on the transaction will trigger a reload of fragment.

Comment: i tried calling pageradapter.notifydatasetchanged() in on progressupdate. it is setting images after completing image download , but for each and every image download, screen is getting refreshed again and again until download completes.

Comment: i tried that also  private void refreshFragments(){
  // WAY1
  // Reload current fragment
  /*MyGallery frg = new MyGallery();
  final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  Bundle data = new Bundle();
  data.putInt("current_page", pagerAdapter.currentItem());
  frg.setArguments(data);
  ft.detach(frg);
  ft.attach(frg);
  ft.commit();*/
  
  //WAY 2 
  
  //pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  
  // WAY 3
  
  //pagerAdapter.getItem(MyGalleryPagerAdapter.mCurrentPage);
 }

Comment: ok if notifyDataSetChanged works for you then try to do it this way. Instead of creating a fresh asynch task for each image download, try to do them in a batch. I had a similar problem but with data not images. I designed my listview to load 8 rows at a time and all 8 as a batch in one loader. And performance improved drastically.

Comment: see my edited question i have included code of asynctask which i use for downloading , i am using oly one task , images are downloaded in for loop one by one

Comment: where is onPostExecute method of the asynch task? you should notify adapters in onPostExecute instead of doInBackground, in case you are not already doing so.

Comment: that is similar to onprogressUpdate. No change in the code. OnPost execute wil get called only after completing the for loop , that means after completing the download of all images. But i wanted the current focussed view to be refershed once its corresponding image is downloaded

Comment: no no. onprogressUpdate is a different thing. onPostExecute is different. Are you doing notify in onprogressUpdate? onprogressUpdate  is called everytime you publish progress, but onPostExecute  is called only once when the doInBackground finishes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52110/discussion-between-ammu-and-nazgul)

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is pager adapter is not getting refreshed. ImageView that was passed to BitmapWorkerTask will get updated after the image is downloaded but you have to find a way to update the pagerAdapter using notifyDataSetChanged in the PagerAdapter. First you need to create Callback from the BitmapWorkerTask to notify the fragment once the download is finished. And then you have to provide a listener back to your PagerAdapter which should call notifyDataSetChanged method once it gets triggered.

Comment: hi , bitmapworkertest is only to decode image file , that will be called in oncreateview of fragment . The issue is oncreateView itself not getting called

Comment: onCreateView() won't be called until pagerAdapter is refreshed but in the previous comment I see that you don't want to refresh pagerAdapter in onProgressUpdate to avoid to many refresh on screen. You can keep the reference in pagerAdapter for the current item (Fragment) and call manually when you want and update the views in Fragment